# Net native toolchain cannot resolve type System.Collections.Generic.ISet

Tags: uwp, .net-native

I have a solution with two UWP projects. One is a library with shared code and the other is a regular UWP app that references the library.

I have successfully developed the app running it in Debug mode. Now I must pack it to the store, that's where NET has given me trouble.

When I compile it in release mode I get the following error

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\.NetNative\x64\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(936,5): error : 
System.TypeLoadException: Could not resolve type 'System.Collections.Generic.ISet`1'.
 in System.TypeNameParser.ResolveType(Assembly assembly, String[] names, Func`4 typeResolver, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
 in System.TypeNameParser.ConstructType(Func`2 assemblyResolver, Func`4 typeResolver, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
 in System.TypeNameParser.GetType(String typeName, Func`2 assemblyResolver, Func`4 typeResolver, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
 in System.Type.GetType(String typeName, Func`2 assemblyResolver, Func`4 typeResolver, Boolean throwOnError)
 in System.Reflection.Adds.TypeNameParser.ParseTypeName(ITypeUniverse universe, Module module, String input, Boolean throwOnError)
 in Microsoft.MetadataReader.MetadataExtensionsPolicy20.TryTypeForwardResolution(MetadataOnlyAssembly assembly, String fullname, Boolean ignoreCase)
 in Microsoft.MetadataReader.MetadataOnlyAssembly.GetType(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)
 in Microsoft.MetadataReader.MetadataOnlyAssembly.GetType(String name, Boolean throwOnError)
 in SerializationAssemblyGenerator.Program.TraverseTypes(GeneratorSettings settings, Dictionary`2& dataContracts, Dictionary`2& jsonDataContracts, List`1& xmlSerializerTypes)
 in SerializationAssemblyGenerator.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

I use ISet a lot so it's natural it is referenced. I have the Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform package version 5.2.2 installed, so I assume its available here. I tried downgrading to version 5.1 but I get the same error. Same if I install the System.Collections package.

Comment: `System.Collections.Generic.ISet` is a namespace used for silverlight app, it can't be used in UWP. Why you want to use this?

Comment: It works on Debug builds so it exists in UWP

Comment: To elaborate on my comment. Years ago I was heavily induced by NHibernate to declare everything as an interface, not the explicit implementation. So I tend to prefer requiring an interface as a parameter, or property, or whatever. I found it useful, and I must be not the only one as the abstractions exists in the framework.

Comment: Standard mishap with Reflection, the .NET Native compiler can only know about types and included them in the native imge that it can see being used in the program.  Edit rd.xml to add the type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I finally made it work. It involved starting another library and moving code from the original, util I caught the problematic class. Very boring as Net Native is soooooo slooooow.

And the culprit was:

```
 private async Task Serialize(ISet<Server> data)
```

this small function serialized a preferences collection using a MemoryStream and DataContractJsonSerializer.

When I changed the signature to

```
 private async Task Serialize(HashSet<Server> data)
```

worked like a charm.

Hope this helps someone in the future.